# How to Set My Firebase Database URL From the Firebase Console

Tags: firebase

where can I get the database URL in my firebase console. Am having difficulties trying to generate the firebase options file so am configuring it myself. Welp!

Comment: Which database URL? The one of the Realtime Database I guess. Also what do you exactly want to do: you use the verbs set and get, so what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean the `databaseURL` property of your Firebase config, it should be `https://<project-name>.firebaseio.com`. To get the full config, go to the "Project Overview" page, click "Add app", then select e.g. "Web", give it a name and the full config will be generated.